# Grep regular expression

Tags: regex, string, grep

I'm having trouble to find with grep some structure in a list of combinations (amino acids).
So it is a list with something like this

```
SIKDQIKNEYNQFAINTQIMSCLPWDPMYLIMETWEHRFSRLGRKEGQEVHDALCPFLNFYHVMRADKWGICRELPAMFH PARSINGS
```

A string of letters, space , a word.
I have to find using `grep` a string of letters which doesn't contain this

`AAA` or `ABA` or `AAB`

in general between two the same letters there have to be two different letters.

Comment: You need as output every line which doesn't contain one of those specific strings or, more generally, lines which don't contain any string of three same characters in a row? Or something else?

Comment: what is d expected otuput

Comment: If I understand correctly, not having pattern `AAB` rules out pattern `AAA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you're trying to do the following:

```
egrep -v '([A-Z])[A-Z]?\1[A-Z]* '
```

This works by finding all instances of `AA` or `ABA` and printing the lines that do not match.